# Program crash when atoi(str) is performed

Tags: c

I dont know why this code keep crashing:

```
int main(void)
{
char input[13];
int i;

fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
i = atoi(input[0]);

return 0;
}
```

If i type '1' (without quotes) the program crash. Compiler is mingw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because `atoi` expects a `char *`. When you give it an `char` in this case, there's nothing to tell the compiler that the value provided isn't really a pointer to something else. And so the program ultimately crashes.

You can change this to either:

`i = atoi(input);`

or

`i = atoi(&input[0]);`

Comment: Not enough rep to comment on the other answer, but if you want the values '1234' individually, you're better off iterating the string, and using charValue - '0' to get the int value.

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` requires a `char *` (C string) not a single `char`. Change:

```
i = atoi(input[0]);
```

to:

```
i = atoi(input);
```

**Also note that you should always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) - if you had done this then the compiler would have helpfully pointed out your mistake for you.**

Comment: So i guess atoi need \0 character. What if i type 1234 and i want each individual digit?